# Recursion depth exceeded on evaluating d = d[[1]]

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting

```
d2 = Import["G:\\mauritius male  death rate(08-10).xlsx"]

{{{0.5, 0.0142}, {2.5, 0.00223}, {7., 0.00158}, {12., 0.00151}, {17., 
   0.0035}, {22., 0.0054}, {27., 0.00751}, {32., 0.01028}, {37., 
   0.01604}, {42., 0.02347}, {47., 0.03576}, {52., 0.05677}, {57., 
   0.07494}, {62., 0.11366}, {67., 0.16382}, {72., 0.23114}, {77., 
   0.32861}, {82., 0.44569}, {85., 0.99999}}}

d = d[[1]]
```

> Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded.<<

Am trying to fit this data in

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[d, b Exp[m x]/(1 + b Exp[m x]), {b, m}, x] // Normal
```

Comment: `d = d[[1]]` will certainly yield an error. Shouldn't it be `d2[[1]]`?

Comment: when am putting d2=d[[1]]  am getting another error Part specification d[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>

Comment: How about this: upload your Excel file somewhere and link to it here, if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: There seems to be two questions here. 1) why OP is getting recursion depth message. 2) How OP can make fit to imported data. Which one is the real question?

Answer (score 4):

So, I think this is what you actually wanted:

```
d2 = {{{0.5, 0.0142}, {2.5, 0.00223}, {7., 0.00158}, {12., 
     0.00151}, {17., 0.0035}, {22., 0.0054}, {27., 0.00751}, {32., 
     0.01028}, {37., 0.01604}, {42., 0.02347}, {47., 0.03576}, {52., 
     0.05677}, {57., 0.07494}, {62., 0.11366}, {67., 0.16382}, {72., 
     0.23114}, {77., 0.32861}, {82., 0.44569}, {85., 0.99999}}};
d = d2[[1]];

logf = LogitModelFit[d, x, x]

Show[Plot[logf[x], {x, 0, 125}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[d, PlotRange -> All]]
```

> 1/(1+Exp[8.81571 - 0.111638 x]

[image]

You can also add weighting to your data.

```
d1 = {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0};
logfw = LogitModelFit[d, x, x, ConfidenceLevel -> 0.9, Weights -> d1]
```

Your original equation yields the following (**when the initial conditions are set**):

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[d, a Exp[b x] /(1 + a Exp[b x]), {{a, 0.001}, {b, 0.001}}, x]
```

> 2.88946*10^-7 Exp[0.190243 x] / 1 + 2.88946*10^-7 Exp[0.190243 x]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But when am doing this its telling me its not a rectangular array?

Comment: @akshay0808 Even with the exact same code posted by Young?

Comment: thanks again mate. It was very helpful.

Comment: Its good now. @MarcoB Thanks

Comment: thanks for update but am working with logistic regressions

Comment: I need to erase this post, Can someone help? else i might get plagiarism situation.

Comment: @akshay, that's not cool. Young here assumed good faith in answering your question, and now you want to have it removed? You should have thought of that first before asking.

Comment: yes i know but i may land in serious trouble

Comment: yes it would be better. Thank you @young

Comment: I can't see how this answer would get you into trouble. The only potential for that  is in the data you posted. If you want to use this answer,  you only need to take care of the site's copyright policy (see below,  currently cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required).

Comment: And I see that you have included similar data in all of your other posts ... what about those

Comment: Guys am writing a dissertation on kannisto logistic regression for mauritian mortality and using these information how do i reference the site just in case

Comment: @akshay0808 http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/citing-stackexchange-postings ... on another note is the answer acceptable?

Comment: @akshay0808 if you are actually concerned about disclosing something you should not, you can delete the question yourself.  I really cant imagine why you would need to cite this in any case.

Comment: @george, actually, since Young's answer has been upvoted, the OP will no longer be able to delete his/her question.